# How to connect .net docker compose to running database container

Tags: .net, sql-server, docker, docker-compose

i am trying to start .net api with docker compose file, it starts and even swagger works , but container doesn't see database, cause i receive an error (i running docker compose on linux)

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

If speaks briefly , i want to connect docker compose api with running ms-sql docker container, is it possible?

my docker compose :

```
    version: '3.4'

services:
  vldonvehicle:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}api
    ports:
      - "8000:5000"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=password
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/cert.pfx
      - DATABASE_PUBLIC_URL=localhost,1433
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Re_VLDonFeedStock_WebApi/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
```

my connection string

```
...
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Initial Catalog=CRMService; Data Source=localhost,1433; Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=password; TrustServerCertificate=True"
  },
...
```

Comment: From a networking perspective each container is its own little Linux VM so `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and `::1` all refer to the current container itself. Since you don't have SQL Server running inside the same container as your ASP.NET Core application `localhost,1433` isn't going to connect to anything. Is the SQL Server container running in the same Docker composition on the same Docker network? If so you should be able to connect to it via its container name, or by its IP address, e.g.: `Server=yourSqlContainerName,1433;` or `Server=172.10.0.25,1433;`

Comment: I already tried `Server=172.10.0.25,1433;`  with my server ip and receive same error , how can i check in which network my container running?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning i tried with mssql container that works on another network `194..., 1433` and it works , so , as i understood my docker compose doesn't see container in same network, perhaps, i must set network in compose file?

Comment: `172.10.0.25` was a made-up address for the example. You'll need to inspect your SQL Server container, either via the Docker Desktop GUI or from a terminal with `docker container inspect yourContainerId` (you can get the Container ID from `docker container ls`), to figure out which IP address it is actually assigned. If you're trying to use Docker container names, though, name resolution will only work if the containers are operating within the same Docker network. You can assign `services` to particular [`networks`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#networks).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thanks for command , it running in network which i created 

`"Networks": { "bridge": {},"vldon-network": {}}` i also edited compose file  `networks: vldon-network:driver: bridge external: true`  but it doesn't work...

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes, i understand that `172.10.0.25` was just an example)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning i found under network setting field with ip address ` "Gateway": "172.23.0.1","IPAddress": "172.23.0.2",` but with it , it also doesn't work...

Comment: @AlwaysLearning i inspect by this command `docker inspect b97f4aee46bb | grep "IPAddress"  "SecondaryIPAddresses": null, "IPAddress": "172.17.0.5",
"IPAddress": "172.17.0.5", "IPAddress": "172.23.0.2",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried same way, but without creating network on another server, and it works perfectly, perhaps, problem in my local web.